# High water pressure compressor for washing bottles

Tags: bottles

Friends often bring me empty bottles. Some of those not washed right after consumption are dirty, so I am looking for a good engineering solution to clean them.

One idea is to use high pressure water supply. Does anybody have experience with that kind of things?

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment, since it really doesn't address your question.  Soaking them in hot water and PBW or Oxiclean or another oxygen based cleaner would be a simpler, less expensive solution.

Comment: Seconding Denny's comment.  Soak them in a large container of Oxiclean for 30-45 minutes and any residual funk on the bottles will come off with a little scrubbing/bottle brush, labels included.  Just make sure you rinse well.

Comment: see http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/in-depth-cleaning-glass-bottles

Comment: Agreed with the above, and I'd be worried if you got the pressure up too high you might end up blowing the ends off the bottles. Which could be dangerous. Much better to let the water and sanitizer do the work for you. And the ones that don't get clean recycle them. Better not to end up with  some dirty beer bottles. Besides you could just get another six pack, drink them and wash the properly.

Comment: Guys, I don't know what is Oxiclean. I couldn't find a similar name in my country.

Comment: I agree with Denny. PBW & Oxiclean are sodium percarbonate cleaners. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OxiClean PBW (powdery brew wash) is more powerful, oxiclean is cheaper, but both work and there are generic versions of oxiclean. You may be able to order PBW from wherever you are ordering your homebrew supplies. Or check a hardware store or wherever you buy cleaning supplies for a percarbonate cleaner. Works best if the water is over 140 degrees F to dissolve the cleaner, but it will work in warm water.

Comment: Don't have oxyclean here in my country too. Search on the clothes washing products, or dishwasher powder. Read the ingredients searching for sodium percarbonate. Avoid that ones with fragrance. I've used Vanish White (for clothes) and Sun (for dishwasher), both works ok. Rinse well.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is probably one that already exists, like the jet bottle washers that attach to your laundry sink.

But if you want an engineering solution, I have seen a design for a home-made keg/carboy washer using a pond pump and plastic bucket/lid that could be adapted for your use:
 1. Add an approximately 12-18" length of PVC pipe to the outflow of the pond pump.  The PVC pipe should be thin enough to fit into the mouth of a     bottle.  This might require using a larger-size PVC pipe to fit to the pump, and then fitting the thinner PVC pipe into the larger one.
 2. Partially fill the plastic bucket with with PBW, Oxy, or other cleaning solution.
 3. Fit an upturned bottle over the pipe.
 4. Hold the lid down on the bucket to keep the bottle from shooting up. You will need to play with the length of the thinner PVC pipe so that the bottom of the upturned bottle touches or almost touches the lid of the bucket, or design some other sort of way to hold the bottle in place (maybe a jig of some sort).
 5. Turn on the pump.

Answer (score 0):

I use a cordless drill bottle brush - http://www.williamsbrewing.com/CORDLESS-DRILL-BOTTLE-BRUSH-P3321C53.aspx

Works great for me, and is a cheap solution as long as you have a drill.